# How to pick a specific element of an array in the frontend and return to controller when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to display all file names and provide a download button for each file, using the following codes: (title of this question maybe not that proper)

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="file in fileCtrl.filesInfo">
  <form method="get" ng-submit="fileCtrl.download()">
    <button type="submit">download</button>
  </form>

  <p> {{file.filename}} </p>
  <hr>
</div>
</div>
```

fileCtrl Controller:

```
// ... some more codes here
var vm = this;

vm.download = function() {

  File // service
    .getFile(filename)
    .success(function(data) {
      //.....
    });
};

// ... some more codes here
```

File service:

```
  fileFactory.getFile = function(filename) {
    return $http.get('/api/files/' + filename);
  };
```

Question: when user click the download button, there will be a specific `filename`, how can I pass the `filename` to controller and let the controller know which file the user want to download, and then execute `.getFile(filename)`?

Comment: Pass `file` to the ngsubmit function like `FileCtrl.download (file)`

Comment: cool, thanks @Parris Varney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a form for this.  Instead, use an `ng-click` action on your button.

```
<div ng-repeat="file in fileCtrl.filesInfo">
  <button ng-click="fileCtrl.download(file.filename)">download</button>
  <p> {{file.filename}} </p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

also note, you should use `.then` instead of the deprecated `.success`.

```
var vm = this;

vm.download = function(filename) {

  File // service
    .getFile(filename)
    .then(function(data) {
      //.....
    });
};
```